# What happens if you make a char *ptr store address of integer variable

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I have the following code snippet

```
int a = 10;
char *p = &a;
printf("%d", *p);
printf("%c", *p);
```

What happens in memory? What will it print and why?

Comment: You get the first 8 bits of the integer, which, on a little endian machine, is the lower 8 bits of the number.  On a big endian machine, it's the upper 8 bits.  Oh, is this homework?  there needs to be a homework tag.

Comment: @ethang homework tag was removed a long time ago.

Comment: What byte-order has your machine? It will (most likely) print either 0 or 10 as a an integer value and as a character. As a character, 0 is invisible, 10 is (normally) newline.

Comment: @ethang You'll get the first *byte*, which is typically 8 bits...but I'm being super-pedantic there.  As "homework" is concerned, a question has the same answer, whether it's *hobby*, *homework*, *work*, etc.

Comment: @DrewDorman, well, as you're pedantic.  It's the first char :p  And yes, it's the same answer, but the approach to getting there may be different.

Comment: @ethang: It was an interview question. I pretty much answered what you said. But it looked like interviewer was not very happy with my answer.

Comment: @San, the interviewer probably wants a number like what Mats Petersson said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char *p = &a;` is a constraint violation. Your compiler must give a diagnostic message, which you shouldn't ignore.

Some compilers will say "warning" and silently transform the code to:

```
char *p = (char *)&a;
```

The effect of this is that `p` still points to the same memory location as `a`, however `p` has a different type. If you read or write through `p` then the memory locations that store the representation of `a` will be treated as if they stored characters. This is called *aliasing*.

Aliasing is permitted to `char` but in general, not permitted for other combinations of types.

Reading `*p` will retrieve the first byte of the storage of `a`. The actual number printed is (probably) implementation-defined; common systems would give `0` or `10`.